# How to get the time difference in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any React-native library that helps getting the difference between two dates. I mean like the following.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zet1.png)

Answer (score 0):

try using moment

```
import moment from 'moment';
 {
                moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                  .month(0)
                  .from(moment().month(0))
}
```

'YYYY-MM-DD' can be whatever format

this one is getting me the difference between the given date and now

here you can find documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/

and here more libraries https://blog.logrocket.com/4-alternatives-to-moment-js-for-internationalizing-dates/